# Laravel job has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-horizon

I am using Laravel 8 with Horizon to track payments asynchronously. The job implementation looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

// use ...

class TrackOrderPayment implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    const RETRY_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 60;


    public function handle()
    {
        // Anticipate errors
        try {

            // implementation ...

        } catch (Throwable $exception) {

            // Re-queue the job
            $this->reQueueJob();

        }
    }


    /**
     * Re-queue the job with a delay to try again later
     */
    private function reQueueJob(): void
    {
        $this->delete();

        if (this->order->status === Constants::ORDER_STATUS_AWAITING_PAYMENT) {
            dispatch(new TrackOrderPayment($this->order))->delay(self::RETRY_INTERVAL_SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

I will wait up to 15 minutes to detect payment, if it's not detected - a separate cron job update the order to a different status, therefore the job will not go back on the queue after 15 minutes (or 15 attempts, since delay between re-queue is set to 60 seconds)

In my `config/queue.php` the redis queue connection config is setup like this:

```php
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 960,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],
```

I don't see any other config in here or `config/horizon.php` regarding max attempts/timeouts.

I am trying to get to the bottom of this, why do some job fails with this error:

> App\Jobs\TrackOrderPayment has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.

All the related question on this topic says raise the `retry_after` and I have done that, it doesn't appear to be helping.

Every time the job runs, the actual "processing" of the job takes < 0.5s, if the payment is not detected it goes back on the queue delayed for 60 seconds.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of configuration from my `config/horizon.php` that shows how to implement the timeout:

```php
'my-supervisor-process' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['default'],
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 1,
    'tries' => 1,
    'timeout' => 120,
],
```

It's possible that the above is not written in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon#configuration), but it does work.

I have been digging through the source code myself to find these parameters myself, anyway I believe the config above is directly related to the following command for which you can see all the options like so (also visible in the class `Laravel\Horizon\SupervisorOptions`):

```
php artisan horizon:supervisor --help
```